# Error in database update query

Tags: c#, database

My system won't update, and it's showing this error, I don't know what to do. Any suggestions? Here's my code

```
 private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();


       string query = "UPDATE [Promissory] SET [pdate] = ?,[Edpno] = ?, [gradingperiod] = ?, [pamount] = ?, [reasons] = ?, [syid] = ? WHERE Promissoryno = ?";

        var accessUpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pdate", txtdate.Text);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Edpno", txtedpno.Text);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("gradingperiod", txtgradeperiod.Text);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pamount", txtamount.Text);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("reasons", txtreasons.Text);
        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("syid", txtsyid.Text);

        accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Promissoryno", txtpromiseno.Text); // Replace "123" with the variable where your ID is stored. Maybe row[0] ?
        da.UpdateCommand = accessUpdateCommand; //This line here is the error
        da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: and what exactly error is?

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: At least one variable of `com`, `con` or `da` is null. Set a breakpoint in the first line of your method and check all of them.

Comment: com, con and da appear from nowhere, so they are being defined somewhere else? Also for a quick hack program doing your data access from a button click event is ok, but for anything more substantial you need to look at breaking your code into modules.

Comment: @LeeWillis i defined com, con and da at the beginning of my code. which is the public partial class Form2 : Form

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on line:

```
com.Connection = con;
```

and step through your code inspecting each variable as you go to see what values they have. One of them will be null. Something is either not being initialised, or is going out of scope and being disposed.